# Can not update user information & ParseCloud.callFunction() missing User information

Tags: android, parse-platform

Whenever I call these query, I can't update user information & ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground() missing user information (request.user in cloud function is null)!

Query#1

```
((User) ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
        .getChats()
        .getQuery()
        .include(CHAT_TEACHER1)
        .include(CHAT_STUDENT1)
        .findInBackground();
```

Query#2

```
ParseQuery.getQuery(Rate.class)
        .include(RATE_RATER)
        .include(RATE_RATETO)
        .include(RATE_LESSON)
        .whereEqualTo(RATE_RATER, ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
        .whereEqualTo(RATE_RATED, false)
        .findInBackground();
```

Query#3

```
ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class)
        .include(MESSAGE_FROM)
        .include(MESSAGE_LESSON)
        .whereEqualTo(MESSAGE_CHAT, ParseObject.createWithoutData(Chat.class, chatId))
        .orderByDescending(MESSAGE_ORDER)
        .setLimit(MESSAGE_PER_PAGE)
        .setSkip(MESSAGE_PER_PAGE * page)
        .findInBackground();
```

Common stuff of these three queries is that all of this query includes currentUser(). Which means all of this query returns list of each object which has relationship with user and currentUser can be included in these query.

Here is my model settings.
User

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class User extends ParseUser {

    public String getFullname() {
        return getString(USER_FULLNAME);
    }

    public void setFullname(@NonNull String string) {
        put(USER_FULLNAME, string);
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new RedrawSettingsViewEvent());
    }

    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return getDate(USER_BIRTHDAY);
    }

    public void setBirthDay(@NonNull Date date) {
        put(USER_BIRTHDAY, date);
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new RedrawSettingsViewEvent());
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return Gender.fromString(getString(USER_GENDER));
    }

    public void setGender(@NonNull Gender gender) {
        put(USER_GENDER, gender.toString());
    }

    public MemberType getMemberType() {
        return MemberType.fromString(getString(USER_MEMBER_TYPE));
    }

    public void setMemberType(@NonNull MemberType memberType) {
        put(USER_MEMBER_TYPE, memberType.toString());
    }

    public Number getPriceMin() {
        return getNumber(USER_PRICE_MIN);
    }

    public void setPriceMin(int integer) {
        if (integer < 0 || integer > 200)
            throw new RuntimeException("Price validation error");

        put(USER_PRICE_MIN, integer);
    }

    public List<Language> getLanguages() {
        return (List<Language>) get(USER_LANGUAGES);
    }

    public void setLanguages(List<Language> languages) {
        put(USER_LANGUAGES, languages);
    }

    public Language getLanguageOf(LanguageLevel languageLevel) {
        List<Language> all = getLanguages();
        if (languageLevel == null || all == null)
            return null;

        for (Language language : all)
            if (languageLevel == language.getLanguageLevel())
                return language;

        return null;
    }

    public List<Language> getSpeakings() {
        List<Language> others = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Language> all = getLanguages();
        if (all == null)
            return others;

        for (Language language : all)
            if (language.getLanguageLevel().getLanguageType() == LanguageLevel.LanguageType.speaking)
                others.add(language);

        return others;
    }

    public ParseRelation<Chat> getChats() {
        return getRelation(USER_CHATS);
    }

    public ParseRelation<Rate> getRates() {
        return getRelation(USER_RATES);
    }

    public void savePinEventually() {
        saveEventually();
        pinInBackground();
    }

    public void savePinEventually(@NonNull SaveCallback saveCallback) {
        saveEventually();
        pinInBackground(saveCallback);
    }

    public void savePinInBackground() {
        saveInBackground();
        pinInBackground();
    }

    public void savePinInBackground(@NonNull final SaveCallback saveCallback) {
        saveInBackground();
        pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    saveInBackground(saveCallback);
                } else {
                    saveCallback.done(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Rate

```
@ParseClassName("Rate")
public class Rate extends ParseObject {

    public Number getRate() {
        return getNumber(RATE_RATE);
    }

    public void setRate(float rate) {
        put(RATE_RATE, rate);
    }

    public User getRater() {
        return (User) getParseUser(RATE_RATER);
    }

    public void setRater(User rater) {
        put(RATE_RATER, rater);
    }

    public User getRateTo() {
        return (User) getParseUser(RATE_RATETO);
    }

    public void setRateTo(User rateTo) {
        put(RATE_RATETO, rateTo);
    }

    public Lesson getLesson() {
        return (Lesson) getParseObject(RATE_LESSON);
    }

    public void setLesson(Lesson lesson) {
        put(RATE_LESSON, lesson);
    }

    public boolean getRated() {
        return getBoolean(RATE_RATED);
    }

    public void setRated(boolean rated) {
        put(RATE_RATED, rated);
    }
}

@ParseClassName("Chat")
public class Chat extends ParseObject {

    public int getNumberOfChatter() {
        Number counter = getNumber(CHAT_NUMBER_OF_CHATTER);
        return counter == null ? 0 : counter.intValue();
    }

    public void setNumberOfChatter(int number) {
        put(CHAT_NUMBER_OF_CHATTER, number);
    }

    public User getTeacher1() {
        return (User) getParseUser(CHAT_TEACHER1);
    }

    public void setTeacher1(User user) {
        put(CHAT_TEACHER1, user);
    }

    public User getStudent1() {
        return (User) getParseUser(CHAT_STUDENT1);
    }

    public void setStudent1(User user) {
        put(CHAT_STUDENT1, user);
    }

    public Date getOrder() {
        Date order = getDate(CHAT_ORDER);
        if (order != null)
            return order;
        else
            return getCreatedAt();
    }

    public void updateOrder() {
        put(CHAT_ORDER, new Date());
    }
}
```

Message

```
@ParseClassName("Message")
public class Message extends ParseObject {

    public Chat getChat() {
        return (Chat) getParseObject(MESSAGE_CHAT);
    }

    public void setChat(Chat chat) {
        put(MESSAGE_CHAT, chat);
    }

    public MessageType getType() {
        return MessageType.fromString(getString(MESSAGE_TYPE));
    }

    public void setType(@NonNull MessageType messageType) {
        put(MESSAGE_TYPE, messageType.toString());
    }

    public User getFrom() {
        return (User) getParseObject(MESSAGE_FROM);
    }

    public void setFrom(User user) {
        put(MESSAGE_FROM, user);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return getString(MESSAGE_TEXT);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        put(MESSAGE_TEXT, text);
    }

    public Lesson getLesson() {
        return (Lesson) getParseObject(MESSAGE_LESSON);
    }

    public void setLesson(Lesson lesson) {
        put(MESSAGE_LESSON, lesson);
    }

    public Date getOrder() {
        Date order = getDate(MESSAGE_ORDER);
        if (order != null)
            return order;
        else if (getCreatedAt() != null)
            return getCreatedAt();
        else
            return new Date();
    }

    public void setOrder(Date order) {
        put(MESSAGE_ORDER, order);
    }
}
```

Here is my application settings

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Language.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Chat.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Message.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Lesson.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Payment.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Payout.class);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Rate.class);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "XXXX");

        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, false);

        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.define('globeeFeed', function(request, response) {

   // Check whether user is logged in
   var user = request.user;
   if (!user)
      return errors.alert(response, null, 'Globee Feed', 'User is not yet logged in.');

   // request.params
   // request.params.languageCode
   // request.params.male
   // request.params.female
   // request.params.priceMin
   // request.params.priceMax
   // request.params.distance
   // request.params.latitude
   // request.params.longitude
   // request.params.seed
   // request.params.page
   // request.params.itemPerPage

   // Check whether parameters are valid
   if (!request.params
      || !request.params.languageCode
      || typeof request.params.male === typeof undefined
      || typeof request.params.female === typeof undefined
      || !request.params.priceMin === typeof undefined
      || !request.params.priceMax === typeof undefined
      || !request.params.distance === typeof undefined
      || !request.params.seed === typeof undefined
      || !request.params.page === typeof undefined)
      return errors.log(response, null, 'Globee Feed', 'Not enough parameters.');
}
```

The request.user is null!

This is not the only problem and I also found which code is making this problem. If I include _User class, somehow user is messed up inside (using localdatastore) and the user information is get lost.

This is what really happens
 1. Open up the app
 2. The app calls query which includes _User class
 3. Close the app and re-open it
 4. User information is lost and cloud code says request.user is null and I can't even edit current user (saveInBackground says error is null but it is not saved in parse server)

Problem with Parse-1.9.2 also. The data doesn't get lost but the query itself is too slow and some phone give me ANR at some point.

I'm using Parse-1.9.4, Bolt-1.2.0.

Comment: Is the problem that ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground() fails because the cloud code doesn't find request.user?  The posted code doesn't show any call to cloud function, nor does it show any cloud code.

Comment: @danh Sorry, I just added cloud code!

Comment: As a debug step, create an MRE for this problem.  An app that does nothing other than log in a known user and call the cloud function.  Have the cloud function do nothing but echo the user... `response.success((request.user)? request.user.id : "no user" );`  delete all of the other code in this question.  If the problem is about getting user in the cloud, lets solve that.

Comment: @danh This is not a problem with cloud code, but it looks the query including _User class mess up current user